# How increment an variable every time ajax success?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am creating a system based on an unstable source ie I monitor every time my application can access this source via ajax successfully.

I created a variable and could not understand how I can increment it each time the success is true.

for example

```
        var i; // my int I want increment every time ajax status is success
        i=0;

        var  req = function(){
            jQuery.ajax({
                success: function(){
                    // but when I'm here i having some problems...

                    //i += i; ? = undefined
                    //i++; ? = 0
                    //i = i+1; ? = 1

                    // I wanted and expected something like => 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
                    //then.. what to do?
                },
                url:'/mysource/',
                type: 'POST',
                data: this.postfields,
            },function(e){});   
        }

            for( var o = 0; o<5; o++ )
                req();
```

Comment: Is it necessary that you define req() as a variable?

Comment: not, I just due it for post, I'm makinga gist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a variable outside of the ajax function and increment it each time:

```
var successCount = 0;
$.ajax(url, function(resp){
  successCount++
});
```

Comment: Erm, how is this different than what the OP's code already does?

Comment: His original post was using var = i

Comment: That was a copy/paste error, according to the OP, which has been fixed. guihknx, please help me understand how this resolved your issue.

Comment: My solution would work and achieves what he was asking. As long the count variable is scoped in a way that isn't re-created when the next ajax call is made, it'll properly retain its value.

Comment: I didn't say otherwise, but you still haven't explained how this is different from the original code. As near as I can tell, the variable is created outside the function in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

i think that your var i is inside a function.
you need to set it as a global var.
if its already is global - its should work fine.

Comment: can you publish the all code on github or something?